# Printing a barcode font on a POS printer

Tags: c++, barcode, gdi

I am trying to use CreateFont to load a Code 128 font so I can output a barcode on a slip. CreateFont is not returning NULL but seems to be failing to find the correct font and is loading something else as I get the code printed as plain text.

This is the barcode function.

```
void EpicSlipPrinter::addBarcode ( const QString& text )
{
  HFONT tempFont = CreateFont ( 60 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 ,0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , 0 , L"Code 128" );
  oFont = (HFONT)SelectObject ( mPrinterHandle , tempFont );

  INT ixPosition = iPaperWidth / 2;

  SIZE sz = getTextDimensions ( text , 3 , 3 , 600 , 0 , 0 );

  SetTextAlign ( mPrinterHandle , TA_CENTER );

  TextOut ( mPrinterHandle , ixPosition , iyPosition , text , text.length () );

  SelectObject ( mPrinterHandle , oFont );
  DeleteObject( tempFont );
}
```

The text parameter is definitely correct so what I think is happening is that CreateFont can't find the specified font and is defaulting to something else. The font is correctly loaded and can be selected from Windows applications, if I type the code into Word then I  get a barcode that can be read from a scanner.

My question is does anyone know why CreateFont is not loading Code 128 or if there is another problem I am missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've specified 0 for the fdwCharSet, which corresponds to ANSI_CHARSET, so the font mapper is looking for something that supports the current code page.  Try using SYMBOL_CHARSET for these kinds of specialty fonts.

Comment: As long as I live I will never understand Microsoft's font mapper. The font name should be the most significant input, but it isn't.

Comment: @Mark Ransom:  The problem with always using the font name is that you wouldn't get font linking when trying to print text in other scripts.  Newer APIs, like DirectWrite, seem to have avoided this charset legacy stuff altogether.

Comment: Although it's not quite consistent with the documentation, I think you can always use DEFAULT_CHARSET, which seems to give precedent to the font name.  (It works with Marlett and other specialty symbol fonts I've tried. 
 I don't have Code 128.)

Comment: Hi sorry for the delay accepting the correct answer. Using SYMBOL_CHARSET worked, I had tried DEFAULT_CHARSET but I must have just somehow missed the existence of symbol. Thanks!

Comment: I just came across this ancient article that has a table at the end of the penalties used by the font mapper for scoring candidate fonts.  Note that the charset is weighed _much_ heavier than the face name.  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms969909.aspx